# ahci: nvme remap support patches and debian-stable

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, patch

I had read about installation of Debian GNU/Linux (among others GNU/Linux distributions) on Lenovo Thinkpads issue few [months](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/44694.html) back. I went again to investigate more and found out that some patches have been [posted](https://marc.info/?l=linux-ide&m=147709610621480&w=2) about one and a half month back. I also looked at some of the back-and-forth [discussions](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-nvme/2016-October/thread.html) but then it sort of stops. Does anybody know what is going on ? Is there going to be support for such affected laptops on say linux 4.9 (hopefully in Stretch) and backported to say linux 3.16 (i.e. Jessie) . Any ideas ?